# How to find similar GPS coordinates in rows of same column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gps, geopandas

Is there a way to identify which GPS coordinates represent same location. e.g. given the following Data Frame. How to tell that Id 1 and 2 are from same source location.

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+
| Id  |    VehLat    |   VehLong   |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
|  66 |   63.3917005 |  10.4264724 |
| 286 |    63.429603 |  10.4167367 |
|  61 |   33.6687838 |  73.0755573 |
|  67 |   63.4150316 |  10.3980401 |
|   5 |    64.048128 |   10.083776 |
|   8 |   63.4332386 |  10.3971859 |
|   9 |   63.4305769 |  10.3927124 |
|   6 |   63.4293578 |  10.4164764 |
|   1 |    64.048254 |   10.084230 |
+-----+--------------+-------------+
```

Now, Ids 5 and 1 are basically same location but what's the best approach to classify these two locations as same.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need this.

```
df[['VehLat','VehLong']].round(3).duplicated(keep=False)
```

You can change the number within `round` to adjust what you consider as "same"

**Output**

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
```

If you want the df itself with duplicate values, you can do as below

```
df[df[['VehLat','VehLong']].round(2).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

OR

```
df.loc[df[['VehLat','VehLong']].round(2).duplicated(keep=False)]
```

**Output**

```
    id         VehLat   VehLong
1   286     63.429603   10.416737
4   5       64.048128   10.083776
7   6       63.429358   10.416476
8   1       64.048254   10.084230
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [Series.between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

> **this allows you greater flexibility when establishing the criteria to**
>   **consider two coordinates as equivalent**

```
df2=df[['VehLat','VehLong']].sort_values(['VehLong','VehLat'])
eq=df2.apply(lambda x: x.diff().between(-0.001,0.001)).all(axis=1)
```

---

```
df2[eq|eq.shift(-1)]
```

**this returns a data frame with equivalent coordinates**

---

```
      VehLat    VehLong
4  64.048128  10.083776
8  64.048254  10.084230
7  63.429358  10.416476
1  63.429603  10.416737
```

---

```
df2[~(eq|eq.shift(-1))]
```

**this returns unique coordinates**

---

```
      VehLat    VehLong
6  63.430577  10.392712
5  63.433239  10.397186
3  63.415032  10.398040
0  63.391700  10.426472
2  33.668784  73.075557
```

---

**you can restore order using [DataFrame.sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)**

```
df_noteq=df2[~(eq|eq.shift(-1))].sort_index()
print(df_noteq)
```

---

```
      VehLat    VehLong
0  63.391700  10.426472
2  33.668784  73.075557
3  63.415032  10.398040
5  63.433239  10.397186
6  63.430577  10.392712
```